# Rspec test not passing because of model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm testing my User model and they can have many aliases:

```
describe User do
  describe "alias associations" do

    before { @user.save }
    let!(:first_alias) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:alias, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
    end

    let!(:second_alias) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:alias, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
    end

    it "User should have many aliases" do
      @user.aliases.should == [first_alias, second_alias]
    end

    it "should destroy associated aliases" do
      aliases = @user.aliases.dup
      @user.destroy
      aliases.should be_empty

      aliases.each do |aliases|
        Alias.find_by_id(alias.id).should be_nil
      end

    end
  end
end
```

My Rspec test is throwing me a loop though. I have a model named Alias and it's giving me this error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_alias, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
        Alias.find_by_id(alias.id).should be_nil
```

When I do `alias.id` it's considered to be a problem.

Why am I getting this error? Is it because of my use of Alias as a model? Changing it to something else gets the test to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several problems here:

1. don't use alias, because it's a reserved word
2. you are passing `aliases` to the block instead of `alias`